# Как сделать, чтобы на странице мог находиться только 1 юзер?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Например, есть некоторая страница, с которой можно управлять данными, и нужно, чтобы туда нельзя попасть, если кто то уже там находится. Навскидку напрашиваются варианты:

- писать в базу, а потом проверять перед заходом, что записи в бд нет
  или она слишком старая;
- завести в контроллере статическое поле.

Собственно, как лучше сделать или у asp.net есть какие то родные механизмы?

Comment: Вы этого для какой цели добиваетесь, что бы несколько пользователей одновременно не могли менять одни и те же данные?

Comment: @sp7, типа того.

Comment: А зачем так делать, в `EF`, если вы его используете, есть же вещи вроде `Timestamp` и `ConcurrencyToken`, которые как-раз таки и позволяют предотвратить момент одновременного редактирования одной записи.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, лучше писать в базу, грубо говоря заводить токен доступа к вашей странице соответствующему пользователю, с временем жизни в несколько минут и с опциональным механизмом "скользящего устаревания" (Sliding expiration).

При входе на страницу, делаете проверку в БД, если токен есть, бросаете 403. Если нет, то создаете.

Опять же, учитываете при доступе к странице, а можно ли вообще пользователю входить на нее.

P.S. Можно писать не только в базу, но в редис, к примеру. Но тут уже вам на усмотрение.

Answer (score 1):

Правильнее писать в базу, причём желательно чтобы у пользователя не оставалось вариантов. Получение "лока" на редактирование базы по кнопочке "Начать редактирование", а сохранить данные можно только по "Сохранить/Отменить и закончить редактирование". Плюс завязаться на закрытие странички и тоже снимать лок. Понятно что всё равно нет гарантии корректного снятия "лока", так что таймаут тоже предусмотреть надо.